# Is there a way to re-write math.ceil function

Tags: python-3.x, math, greedy, ceil, floor-division

For this function, I must find all the "Egyptian fractions" that add up to a fraction using a greedy algorithm. All Egyptian fractions have a numerator value of 1, they are distinct, and the sum = (numerator/denominator). I understand how to find one using division and math.ceil. However, the function never seems to resolve after I try with values for numerator and denominator. Is there a way to re-write my code using no division (i.e. no ceiling, division, or floor), just multiplication and subtraction? I can assume the numerator is always < denominator, and both are positive integers.

```
def egypt(numerator, denominator):
    fracs = []
    while numerator != 0:
        n = int(numerator)
        d = int(denominator)
        c = math.ceil(d / n)
        fracs.append(c)
        n = (c*n) - d
        d = c*d
    return fracs
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "the function never seems to resolve after I try with values for numerator and denominator"? Do you mean that the approximations of floating-point math are causing you trouble? Which particular input gives you trouble for the code you show? There are ways of doing this exactly, using integer division `//` and modulus `%`, avoiding regular division `/` and `math.ceil`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Your `numerator` never changes, so `while numerator != 0` will either be always true or never true -- either the loop doesn't run or it's an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

`math.ceil` is OK. The problem is that you reinitialize the cycle each time. Here is the fixed function:

```
def egypt(numerator, denominator):
    fracs = []
    n = int(numerator)
    d = int(denominator)
    while n != 0:
        c = math.ceil(d / n)
        fracs.append(c)
        n = (c*n) - d
        d = c*d
    return fracs
```